C# Linq All in Where condition
I had the following LinqExpression:
var results = _localDatabase.Table<ArticleData>()
                            .Where(article => article.ArticleName!.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower());

Which had the disadvantage, that the text that has been searched had to be part of the ArticleName. But sometimes, users only enter parts of words (ArticleName is "Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse" and users search for "man" and "verse").
So I split the search query in individual parts:
string[] splitQuery = searchQuery.Split(' ');

And tried to search for the individual parts:
var results = _localDatabase.Table<ArticleData>()
                            .Where(article => splitQuery.All<string>(queryPart => article.ArticleName!.Contains(queryPart)));

Which in theory, sounded great, but in practice, I got an error

Cannot compile: Lambda

TLDR
I need a way to pack something  like this all method, or something like this into the linq expression.
Edit
I have a SQLite database. With _localDatabase.Table<ArticleData>(), I get a queryable object.

Please clean up the question and explain what you're actually using. LINQ doesn't query databases. EF has no Table<T>. ORMs deal with O-bjects, not tables. Perhaps you use the ancient LINQ-to-SQL ? In any case, starting another task to run the query won't make anything faster. If your ORM has a ToListAsync method it won't block the current thread nor will it start another blocked thread

It's unclear what you want to query too. The query as is can't use any indexes do to the string transformations and will have to scan the entire table. Databases have Full Text Search indexes and operations to search multiple fields for words or their variations. What database and what ORM are you using? There may be a way to write an FTS query using the ORM. Otherwise you'll have to use eg Dapper with a SQL query

Thanks, @PanagiotisKanavos for the Feedback :D
I am in a Blazor App, which loads a SQLite Database. I'm using SQLite-net to connect to it, and it uses Linq-Expressions (as far as I understood) to query.
I also saw the Full Text Search, but this is nothing SQLite provides.

You can use an individual Where clause for each item in splitQuerry:
var query = _localDatabase.Table<ArticleData>().AsQueryable();
foreach(var item in splitQuerry )
{
    query = query.Where(article => article.ArticleName!.ToLower().Contains(item.ToLower()));
}
query = query.Skip(startIndex ?? 0).Take(requestedNumberOfItems ?? 5);
var result = query.ToList();


that seems to work. Thanks a lot :D
By the way, you missed a query in query = *query*.Skip...
